# Many calls of newsletter_subscriber_save_before Observer

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer

In my Observer, I noticed that `newsletter_subscriber_save_before` Observer calls in many other actions, for example `customer_login` or `customer_register_success`.

The problem is, that I use `newsletter_subscriber_save_before` for check status of subscription in Customer Account and in Unsubscribe Link from Email message, but I don't want to call `newsletter_subscriber_save_before` on Login Action.

Is there any other events that I could use to replace `newsletter_subscriber_save_before` in Customer Account and Unsubscribe Link, and at the same time will not be calling on Login or Register?

Comment: I did not try. But maybe `newsletter_subscriber_save_after` can help you.

Comment: Nope. It is doing that same thing.

Comment: Please use markdown to properly format your posts. You already tried to _mark_ code fragments/identifiers (such as `customer_login`), but used ordinary single quotes ' ' instead of the correct ``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look in newsletter core module, I didn't find any useful events for you.

But in your observer you can easily track for which controller action it was ran.

So you can take module, controller and action names and check them before executing your code.

```
$request        = Mage::app()->getRequest();
$moduleName     = $request->getModuleName();
$controllerName = $request->getControllerName();
$actionName     = $request->getActionName();
if (
    $moduleName != 'customer' && 
    $controllerName != 'accout' && 
    $actionName != 'login'
) {
    //your observer code here
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I did not came up with that idea :) It helps me a lot. Thank you.